# script.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener') at script.js:21:15

Tags: javascript, web, frontend

`I m am getting this error in console. For my JavaScript`

var onepro = document.getElementsByClassName('pro')

```
var mainimg = document.getElementById('MainImg');

for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    onepro[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        console.log('done')
        window.location.href = 'sproduct.html';
        mainimg.src = "img/products/f4.jpg";
        
    })
    
  }
```

> here onepro and mainimg are from two different html files connected by this js file

> Actually i am tying to replace image of one html file to other html file on click ``

Comment: your question is not clear, please read [ask] and create [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.